# Copy symbolic link and the file in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, symlink

I have a temp directory structure like below :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep  9 11:37 file1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep  9 11:38 file2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Sep  9 11:38 LATEST -> file1
```

I want to copy the LATEST symbolic link and the file/folder it is pointing to. For now I am using `cp -d` which copies only the symbolic link and not the the file it is pointing to. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94714/cp-l-vs-cp-h

Comment: @darecoder : You did not post the `cp` command you have tried, and it is not clear what you want to achieve: The idea to copy a symlink **together** with the original file does not make much sense to me, except when thinking of the use case of creating a copy of a complete directory tree somewhere, and **all** the symlinks are only inside this tree. In this case, you would however not use `cp` for creating the copy, but `rsync`, which gives you much more control over the copying process.

Comment: ```cp -d LATEST /home/target/``` this is the command i used. both symlink and the file are in the same location. My use case here is to take a backup for this folder. @user1934428

Comment: Aren't you missing the option `-r`? Aside from this: Are the symlinks relative or absolute? If they are relative, your command should already do what you want. If it doesn't, post a case where it produces an incorrect copy.

Comment: So, in this case you want to copy the symlink target, whatever it is, and the symlink itself, but not anything else?

Answer (score 2):

You could find name of the file/folder with `realpath`, copy it, and then create a new link at the destination:

```
cp_with_link(){
    src="$1"
    srcdir="${1%/*}"
    srcbase="${1##*/}"
    dstdir="$2"

    if ! [ -d "$srcdir" ] || ! [ -L "$src" ]; then
        echo 1>&2 source symlink does not exist
        return 1
    fi
    if ! [ -d "$dstdir" ]; then
        echo 1>&2 destination directory does not exist
        return 2
    fi

    realsrc=$(realpath "$src")

    if ! [ -f "$realsrc" ] || ! [ -d "$realsrc" ]; then
        echo 1>&2 source symlink points to non-existent location
        return 3
    fi

    realbase="${realsrc##*/}"

    cp -R "$realsrc" "$dstdir/$realbase"
    ln -s "$realbase" "$dstdir/$srcbase"
}


cp_with_link "/path/to/temp/dir/LATEST" "/home/target"
```

Using `realpath` and recreating the symlink allows handling the case where the symlink originally points outside the source directory.

Comment: Or some sources recommend `realpath` over `readlink`.  The former's options are a bit different but it can work here, too.

Answer (score -1):

`cp -rL /source /destination`

The `-r` parameter is for recursive, if you would like to.
The `-L` parameter is to follow the symlink and expand this and then copy the contents.

Comment: if you do it on the link, you will rename the destination file/folder and the subsequent `cp -d` will fail